# JQuery binding item index to another items index

Tags: jquery

I have scroller using Jquery Tools Scrollable which scrolls through items fine. Separate to this I have a list which matches the items being scrolled through. I need to add a class to the correct list item based on the scroller's index. The best way I can think of is to use the navigator on the scoller to set the selected list item.

My question is therefore can I bind the index of one element (navigator) to my list element?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To further explain scrollable is a JQuery plugin, i'm not referring to the Window scroll event. http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scrollable/navigator.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you bind an handler to the scroll event and check whatever you want to check there?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   // check your list and bind the class accordingly here
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: Hi ChuckE. Thanks for the response, but not quite what i'm after. I've updated my original post to explain more.